# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type, but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

After executing the application, I get the

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.StudentDetail[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.ServiceClient].

In view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.ServiceClient>
....
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

DbController.cs

```
public class DbController : Controller
{ 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ServiceReference1.ServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        return View(obj.GetStudents()); 
    } 
}
```

My iService.cs

```
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<StudentDetail> GetStudents();
```

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You call a service that returns `List<StudentDetail>` and pass it to a view which expects `IEnumerable<ServiceClient>` - `StudentDetail` is **not** `ServiceClient`

Comment: Try changing 'IEnumerable<MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.ServiceClient>' to 
'IEnumerable<StudentDetail>'

Comment: New error

Compiler Error Message: CS0426: The type name 'StudentDetail' does not exist in the type 'MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.ServiceClient'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes.

```
public ActionResult Index()
  { 
     ServiceReference1.ServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
     return View(obj.GetStudents().ToList()); 
  }
```

Change the View as follows.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.ServiceClient.StudentDetail>
```

**Edit**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.StudentDetail>
```

**Display Students**

You need to print the values of student properties in your StudentDetail class
something like "item.StudentName". StudentName is a property in your class.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td> item.StudentName </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't recognize my "StudentDetail"; gives me the squiggly line.

Comment: @Ollivander Try closing and opening the view again. Intellisense doesn't work always when importing namespaces on view. It should compile and run though.

Comment: New error: Compiler Error Message: CS0426: The type name 'StudentDetail' does not exist in the type 'MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.ServiceClient'

Comment: Thank you, that works. I'm doing a tutorial that uses a web service to interact with a database. However, after using your edit, it does not display the students in the database as intended. It just displays an empty list, with "Create", "Edit", "Details" and "Delete". I'm new using mvc, but shouldn't it display my list

Comment: Hi, so I have my View working. I am trying to have CRUD operations in my application for the student records. Can you help me with the codes for this?